# Is it possible to have an auto-generated string uniqueidentifier that auto-populates when entering data in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I've converted a primary int Id key to a string (nvarchar(450), however I want to have it autogenerate new IDs (Guid "Style" but string-formatted, which seems to be the way ASP.NET Core sets up their key columns now?) when new records are created in our ASP.NET Core app but also ideally in SSMS when I'm adding a new row manually, and wondering if that's possible.  As it stands, I'm getting an error when I try to update this via a migration script:

```
migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey(
name: "PK_ml",
table: "ml");


migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
table: "ml",
name: "Id",
nullable: false,
type: "uniqueidentifier",
defaultValueSql: "newid()",
oldClrType: typeof(string));

migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey(
name: "PK_ml",
table: "ml",
column: "Id");
```

The error I get is:

> Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
> The statement has been terminated.

Based on the comments below, I've updated my migration script to the following:

```
migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey(
name: "PK_ml",
table: "ml");

 migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
 name: "Id",
 table: "ml");

 migrationBuilder.AddColumn<Guid>(
 name: "Id",
 table: "ml",
 type: "uniqueidentifier",
 nullable: false,
 defaultValue: "NEWID()");

 migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey(
 name: "PK_ml",
 table: "ml",
 column: "Id");

 // Update the existing data in the table to populate the new GUID column.
 migrationBuilder.Sql(
 @"UPDATE ml SET Id = NEWID()");
```

But I'm still getting an error:

> Conversion failed when converting from a character string to
> uniqueidentifier.
> The statement has been terminated.

Comment: If you want it to contain a guid you should use the uniqueidentifier datatype, not an nvarchar(450). And all you have to do is use a default on the table definition. I hope when you say `adding a row manually` you mean an insert statement and not that dreadful `edit top rows` thing.

Comment: An `nvarchar(450)` for the primary key also makes little sense; that's means you're stating the value could be up to 900 bytes in length, which is a *huge* number of different possible storage values.

Comment: Adding a default won't change the existing values. You are going to need to create a new column, assign values to it, and do a switcheroo/rename.

Comment: Ok, I've taken your comments into view and made some edits to my script but still getting an error - I've edited the main post with the updated script and error.
 @Charlieface, But I decided to drop the column entirely and recreate it.  The values in it currently aren't important as there are no current tables that have this column as a foreign key.

Comment: That looks OK except that you don't need the final `UPDATE` step. Can you put a trace on the server to see what exact statements are being executed?